# What does this Javascript statement mean?

Tags: javascript

what exactly is going on with this javascript statement:

```
var loadPrevious = (loadPrevious || function() {});
```

From my understanding, the variable loadPrevious is either going to be an anonymous function or the value loadPrevious

EDIT:

ok great thanks for the answers and comments.  But why then would there be a statement like this:

```
var app;
loadPrevious(app = launchApplication($("#target"),0));
```

what does loadPrevious do here?  And why do it this way?

Comment: Your understanding is correct - `loadPrevious` will either retain its current value, or if it doesn't have one, initialise an empty function.

Comment: it doesn't look like anyone answered the second question in your edit. work your way inside out with that statement. first, jquery is used to get a reference to an html element with id 'target'. that is then passed to the launchApplication() function, who's value is assigned to var app. then, loadPrevious() is called with the value assigned to app, and a second param of zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it checks to see if loadPrevious has already been assigned a value. if not, it assigns it an empty function.

this syntax is the javascript equivalent of the C++ or C# ternary syntax

```
var loadPrevious = loadPrevious != null ? loadPrevious : () => {};
```

in C#, for example.

Answer (score 3):

The code is checking if `loadPrevious` has been defined, and if not it defines it as an anonymous function.

This pattern is useful in cases where you are adding methods to an object from several different places, eg:

method1.js:

```
var loadPrevious = (loadPrevious || function() {});
loadPrevious.prototype.method1 = function() { return 'method1'; };
```

method2.js:

```
var loadPrevious = (loadPrevious || function() {});
loadPrevious.prototype.method2 = function() { return 'method2'; };
```

Now you can include both of those files, and loadPrevious will have both methods:

```
<script src="method1.js"></script>
<script src="method2.js"></script>
<script>
    var oLoadPrevious = new loadPrevious();
    oLoadPrevious.method1(); // "method1"
    oLoadPrevious.method2(); // "method2"
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, it will be the value of `loadPrevious` unless it evaluates to false, in which case it will be the empty anon function

Answer (score 1):

This is a **OR ||** condition right

```
var loadPrevious = loadPrevious || function() {}
```

If the loadPrevious is true then it skips the next condition .

So it will assigned to `function(){}` only if it is not defined..